# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to 2} \frac{1}{\sin{\pi x}}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to 2} \frac{1}{\sin{\pi x}}$ ?

For $x\to 2$, I get: $\frac{1}{0}$.

Comment: Are you sure that there is exist the limit ?

Comment: The limit does not exist.

Comment: the limit is undefined

Comment: What can you conclude if you get $1/0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$\lim\limits_{x\to 2-0} \frac{1}{\sin{\pi x}}= - \infty$

and

$\lim\limits_{x\to 2+0} \frac{1}{\sin{\pi x}}= + \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to2}\frac{1}{\sin(\pi x)} = \lim_{t\to0}\frac{\pi t}{\pi t \sin(\pi t)}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{\pi t} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{t}$, which doesn't exist, because I could get $\epsilon = \frac{1}{\delta + 1}$ and for all $\delta$: $\frac{1}{\delta} > \frac{1}{\delta + 1}$.